# How to add another column to my dataframe, that is a count of my other column "tags"

Tags: python, count, calculated-columns

I am very new to python and I am trying to count the number of tags within a string.

I've found people saying to count the comma's then + 1 which makes sense. what doesn't make sense is how to make this into a column that applies to every row.
My data frame is called data and is set like below:

```
product_id  sku       total_sold  tags           total_images 
grgeggre    rgerg     456         Up1_, Up2      5
```

I want it to look like the below:

```
product_id  sku       total_sold  tags           total_images  total tags
grgeggre    rgerg     456         Up1_, Up2      5             2
```

I've tried:

```
tgs = data['tags']
tgsc = tgs.count("," in data["tags"] + str(1))
print(tgsc)
```

which doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: apologies for the format it shouldn't show like that, can someone let me know how to format it into a table?

Comment: Can you share the columns and one row of values as an example and I could help you format it?

Comment: It is in there, I just edited it, should be viewable soon. First row starts with `grgeggre`

Comment: In that case, just use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ and generate an ascii table. Once ready put it within code blocks

Comment: @Sharath thanks i'll note this for next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple lambda function for apply should do the trick:

```
data["total_tags"] = data["tags"].apply(lambda x : len(x.split(',')))
```

Explanation:
DataFrame.apply():

> Apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame.
>   Objects passed to the function are Series objects whose index is either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the DataFrame’s columns (axis=1). By default (result_type=None), the final return type is inferred from the return type of the applied function. Otherwise, it depends on the result_type argument.

See [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

So we apply a function (the lambda function) to each row of the dataframe of the column `"tags"`.
The lambda function is an anonymous function in this case with `x` as "input arguments" and `len(x.split(','))` as function body. So this funnction is applied to each row of the column `"tags"`.
For `split()` see [str.split documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it splits the string at the defined delimiter into an array. The length of this array is the number of comma divided tags.

Hope this explanation helped

Comment: thanks! that worked a treat! Can you explain how you've structured this and what it does so i can learn from it rather than just copy and paste the code, it would be much appreciated.